# Add a subdomain to a Heroku App

Tags: heroku, subdomain

I have create a Heroku App which is called `database-service` which has the following URL assigned:

`https://database-service.herokuapp.com/`

Is it posible to add a `subdomain` called `test` so I can access the exact same app?

E.g.

`https://test.database-service.herokuapp.com/`

Comment: Hello, I am having the same problem and wondering if you found a solution.

Comment: The workaround I found was creating subdomains in my domain provider (GoDaddy) and bind that to Heroku in `Settings -> Domains and certificates`